# Ionic - Infinite Scroll with no display

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I'm a bit new with Ionic and I would like to use the infinite-scroll component with my own datas.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InfiniteScroll } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-administrateur',
    templateUrl: 'administrateur.html'
})
export class Administrateur {
    infiniteScroll: InfiniteScroll;
    users = [
        {firstName : "Julie", lastName : "Aubret", mail : "julieaubret@outlook.fr"},
        {firstName : "Thomas", lastName : "Perrot", mail : "thomasperrot@outlook.fr"},
        {firstName : "Maxime", lastName : "Le Feuvre", mail : "maximelefeuvre@outlook.fr"},
        {firstName : "Mewen", lastName : "Le Pogam", mail : "mewenlepogam@outlook.fr"},
        {firstName : "Aziliz", lastName : "Abollivier", mail : "azilizabollivier@outlook.fr"},
        {firstName : "Thibault", lastName : "Herledan", mail : "thibaultherledan@outlook.fr"},
        {firstName : "Sophie", lastName : "Puybareau", mail : "sophiepuybareau@outlook.fr"},
        {firstName : "Kévin", lastName : "Le Manach", mail : "kevinlemanach@outlook.fr"}
    ];
    page = 0;
    maximumPages = 3;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.loadUsers();
    }

    loadUsers(infiniteScroll?) {
        if (infiniteScroll) {
            infiniteScroll.complete();
        }
    }

    loadMore(infiniteScroll) {
        this.page++;
        this.loadUsers(infiniteScroll);
        if (this.page === this.maximumPages) {
            infiniteScroll.enable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem : When I look at the result, it seems that the function which loads my datas only display the list without displaying the informations.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CooB2.png)

What do I need do I need to do in order to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! While screenshots can be useful to help understanding what's happening, image of codes are strongly discouraged [for various reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please edit your question and add the most relevant part of the codes and any messages in the question itself. Your question will be better received if you provide a [mcve].